# How can I create a constraint on pairs of nodes based on their labels and attributes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints

Let's say i have two different nodes in my DB:

```
(p:person {name: "Claudia"})-[:likes]->(h:hobby {name: "football", experience: "2 years"})
```

My goal is to make each person's hobby unique by its `name` attribute, but at the same time I want to be able to create another `(h:hobby {name: "football"})` node, related to some other `person` and it would be 2 different nodes (it's important!).

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT FOR (h:hobby),(p:person) REQUIRE (p:person)-[:likes]->(h.name) IS UNIQUE
```

but it doesn't even work, giving me:

```
Invalid input '(': expected ")" or an identifier (line 2, column 6 (offset: 24))
"FOR ((h:hobby),(p:person))"
```

**SOLUTION:**

In [Finbar's Good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77215248/20132179) I found useful statement: `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

I can guarantee each `person` has only one related `(h:hobby {name: "football"})` node using this statement and I can add `uuid` property for each `hobby` node I create to make sure it's unique  within the database:

```
MATCH (p:Person { name: "Claudia" })
WHERE NOT EXISTS { (p)-[:LIKES]->(:Hobby {name: "football"}) }
CREATE (p)-[:LIKES]->(:Hobby {name: "football", experience: "2 years", id: apoc.create.uuid()})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `CONSTRAINT` on node-relationship-node combinations.

It could be enforced in a DML statement for creating the relationship. For example:

```
MATCH (p:Person { name: "Claudia" })
WHERE NOT EXISTS { (p)-[:LIKES]->(:Hobby {name: "football"}) }
CREATE (p)-[:LIKES]->(:Hobby {name: "football", experience: "2 years"})
```

This assumes the hobby might not already exist.

Comment: This solution should just use `WHERE NOT EXISTS { (p)-[:LIKES]->(:Hobby {name: "football"}) }`. That is, to ensure that the user has no existing `Hobby` with the same `name`, the filter should only check the `name` property.

Comment: @cybersam thanks, didn't spot that nuance in the question. Updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my question with a solution, that use your suggestion.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it solves your question 

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change the data model slightly (don't know if that is a feasible option for you) so that you make Hobby unique by name for all. So there would only be one Hobby node with name "football" and all who likes football would point to the same node. That way you could have a uniqueness constraint on the name of Hobby.

With this model you would move the experience property to the relationship instead (so that the LIKES relationship would have the experience property).

However, this would not prevent the same person node to have multiple LIKES relationships to the same Hobby, but at least the same Hobby would only exist once.

Comment: It's a good solution, but, unfortunately, in my case there could be similar, but at the same time unique `hobby` nodes. It's just what I can't change. Anyway, thanks for your answer!